# Ionic 1 migration to Ionic 2: Package name must look like: com.company.Name

Tags: android, ionic2, cordova6.4.0

Last year I created an ionic 1 app and used app id with dash in it (e.g. com.e-something.app) and I successfully published this app to google play store... Now that I want to migrate to ionic 2 I can't use same id... When I run

```
$ ionic platform add android
```

I get the following error

> Package name must look like: com.company.Name

I googled for this error and found out that dashes are not allowed (anymore???) for app id...

I want to use the same id so I can update existing app on play store. I don't want to publish it as a completely new app.

What can I do in this situation?

Comment: did you got any solution ???

Comment: no... the only solution I found was to change id and publish it as new app....